# Access instance of a class in another class

Tags: java, oop, instance

I'm very new to coding and have a strict deadline for this assignment so I couldn't find an explanation I understood very well so I am asking here.

I am makign an instance of my Pokemon class in a another class for my main game. I however need info on how many times a pokemon was defeated in my catch pokemon class as I want a user to only be able to catch a pokemon if they've beat it a certain amount of times. I have no clue how to do this however.

This is how the class is used if it is of any help:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Battle extends JFrame{

public Pokemon fire = new Pokemon("Charmander", "Fire");
public Pokemon water = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Water");
public Pokemon plant = new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "Grass");
public Pokemon ground = new Pokemon("X", "Ground");
```

I have tried something like Battle.pikachu.toString() in the main class to just test how to access it because that is what someone else told me but the battle part confuses me as I don't think it is actually referrign to anything when in my main class.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to "have a strict deadline" if you're "new to coding". Maybe you should look for another employer soon if you don't want to be a slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define your `Pokemon` inside a `Battle`. You should instead pass your `Pokemon` into this `Battle` class.

So you should instead define your Pokemon in your Main class:

```java
public class Main {
  // Your functions...

  private ArrayList<Pokemon> getMyPokemons() {
    ArrayList<Pokemon> myPokemonList = new ArrayList<>();
    Pokemon fire = new Pokemon("Charmander", "Fire");
    Pokemon water = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Water");
    Pokemon plant = new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "Grass");
    Pokemon ground = new Pokemon("X", "Ground");
    myPokemonList.add(fire);
    myPokemonList.add(water);
    myPokemonList.add(plant);
    myPokemonList.add(ground);
    return myPokemonList;
  }

  private void triggerBattle() {
    ArrayList<Pokemon> myPokemonList = getMyPokemons();
    Battle battle = new Battle(myPokemonList);
  }
}
```

And in your `Battle` class,

```java
public class Battle extends JFrame {
  private ArrayList<Pokemon> myPokemons;
  // Create constructor to receive your Pokemon
  public Battle(ArrayList<Pokemon> myPokemons) {
    this.myPokemons = myPokemons;
  }

  // And in other functions within this class, you can access
  // myPokemons list
}
```

And of course if you need more information related to the `Pokemon`, you need to refer to @Boycpu suggestion and add more attributes to your `Pokemon` class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
public class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private String group;
    private int defeatedTimes;

    public Pokemon(String name, String group, int defeatedTimes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pass = group;
        this.defeatedTimes = defeatedTimes;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public int getDefeatedTimes() {
        return defeatedTimes;
    }

    public void setDefeatedTimes(int defeatedTimes) {
        this.defeatedTimes = defeatedTimes;
    }
}
```